How do I fix NetBeans Clean and Build Error (error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 17)
ant -f C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall clean dist
init:
undeploy-clean:
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build
check-clean:
clean:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web\META-INF
Copying 75 files to C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web\WEB-INF\lib
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Created dir: C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\tedzkie\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\WakeUpCall\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 17
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
idk why I get this error. At first it said target "21", but when I changed my jdk version to 17, and even changed the .conf file to 17, it only changed the target to 17 instead of fixing it. Can you guys help me. Im still new to java.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

See error: option -Xbootclasspath/p: not allowed with target 12 (Netbeans 11.0). Obviously you are using different versions of Java and NetBeans and the accepted answer won't help you, but the workaround in the answer from Ernestas Gruodis should still resolve your problem. It has worked for me. If it doesn't help then update your question accordingly.

in project.properties try removing the value in endorsed.classpath=
